# An abstract class should have both abstract and concrete methods workaround

Tags: java, inheritance, sonarqube

SonarQube is giving me this error: "An abstract class should have both abstract and concrete methods" for this class:

```
public abstract class Person {

protected String emailAddress;
protected String firstName;
protected String lastName;
protected Timestamp createdDate;

// public getters and setters
```

I use this class to achieve inheritance to this DTO's

```
public class FacultyDTO extends Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer userId;

private Integer clientId;

private String status;

// getters and setters for fields above

public class StudentDTO extends Person implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Integer studentId;

// getters and setters for fields above
```

But Sonar says to modify Person to be a concrete class with private constructor, with that, then i could not extend it to achive inheritance. What i'm doing is bad practice?

Comment: Inheritance is a poor tool for code reuse. This might be a time to prefer composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

From documentation

> The purpose of an abstract class is to provide some heritable behaviors while also defining methods which must be implemented by sub-classes.

> A class with no abstract methods that was made abstract purely to prevent instantiation should be converted to a concrete class (i.e. remove the abstract keyword) with a private constructor.

--> You are here. So this is why sonar display this rules as violated.

> A class with only abstract methods and no inheritable behavior should be converted to an interface.

Comment: Ok then, but then by the documentation it should be a concrete class with private constructor, with that meaning i could not extend it to my DTO's. So what do you think about this. Could this be only a normal class?

Comment: Are you assuming that or have you tried making the change.... the IDE will let you know if extending a class with private constructor is possible or not.

Comment: Yeah i did that but IntelliJ tells me this: "here is no default constructor available in 'com.dtos.Person'", so that's why i'm a bit clueless

Comment: Yes and if you add that propably something like this appears: _Implicit super constructor Super() is not visible. Must explicitly invoke another constructor_. Meaning you need to add some parameterized constructor.

Comment: ok then, but what i don't understand is if i have this constructor with params, then why would i do this instead of doing the constructor public all the way then?

Answer (score -1):

> Sonar says to modify Person to be a concrete class with private
> constructor

That sounds stupid. Who would want to declare a concrete class only with a private constructor? Well unless you are doing something like singleton / static only, which is not the case here.

What I would suggest in your case is to drop the abstract keyword and add a protected constructor to your Person class. That way you can keep Sonar happy, hopefully.

```
public class Person {

protected Person() { }
```